No Condition definition item could be found for Id
We are seeing a odd issue in our prod environment after a 10.3 upgrade. The processing website keeps throwing A LOT of these errors.
ERROR [Experience Analytics]: RulesValidator failed to process interaction '6f5786ee-7424-0200-0000-0703f3ba7a5c' segment '0df6797e-ee1b-4bfd-9262-0471b1add438' - DescriptorId : c5b7e4d8-9598-4e36-aa33-828698a2d773
Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.PredicateDescriptorException: No Condition definition item could be found for Id 'c5b7e4d8-9598-4e36-aa33-828698a2d773' in database 'master'.
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.ContentTreePredicateDescriptorLocator.GetDescriptor(Guid id)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.PredicateFactory.DefaultPredicateFactory.Create(Guid descriptorId, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 properties)

The GUID it reports changes. Sometimes it is marketing automation plan items, sometimes path analyzer items other times custom content items.
If I take that GUID at search in the CM UI I always find it. So it does exist in the master database. We have checked and double-checked our connection strings for the process website and it is pointed to the correct master database.
In our lower environments, where we also upgrade from version 9.3 to 10.3, we do not encounter this issue.
Does anyone have any idea what is triggering this?
Unregistering this stops the errors but not sure why.
<register
        serviceType="Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Client.ProcessingEngineClient, Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Client"
        implementationType="Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Client.WebApiProcessingEngineClient, Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Client"
        lifetime="Singleton" />


We are also experiencing the same issue, continuously encountering this exception on the processing server. We have tried all the suggested steps. Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Can you try checking if the missing items are there on the sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master index, because these items are fetched from the marketing index.

In case these items are not there, you can try rebuilding sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master index from the Control Panel and also check connection to Solr is proper without any issue from the processing server.
Hope this helps!!!

The GUID is not found in the sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master index. I also rebuilt the index just to see as well and even after a rebuild the item is not in that database. I also validated the "solr.search" connection string in the processing website.

@ToddB is the marketing definitions index empty? Can you try redeploying marketing definitions once from Control Panel as well.

It is not empty. There are 6166 items in the index. I have deployed the definitions as well. The items it can't find are normally lists or rules.
